# Would I need to pay taxes for crossing border with a Violin outfit?

Tags: taxes, india, customs, bangladesh

I want to buy a violin outfit (aka "set": violin, bow, and case sold as a unit) from India and take it back to Bangladesh. Do I need to pay taxes for the newly bought violin?

Comment: Are you asking about taxes that you will have to pay in India on the purchase price of the violin (things like GST for example, or VAT) or export duties imposed by India or customs duties imposed by Bangladesh on the importation of the violin, or are you asking whether Bangladesh will impose sales tax or excise tax or luxury task or any other kind of tax that a babu might dream up?

Comment: I'm talking about taxes on product that I'm bringing back to Bangladesh as import tax

Comment: I think this link may help. http://www.bangladeshcustoms.gov.bd/relevant/baggage_rules the document is in Bangla